# Are the http requests to a HttpServlet handled asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I've been told that the java servlets may run asynchronously. But does that mean that the requests to a single servlet are handled asynchronously, or that only the requests to different servlets are asynchronous.

Basically, I have this one servlet in my project:

```
public class DummyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream());

    writer.write("DummyServlet invocation");

    System.out.print("Invocation: " + counter);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.out.println(" ... done.");
    counter++;

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Now, when I make two simultaneous requests, the second waits for the first to end.
How can one achieve asynchronous behavior in this scenario?

UPDATE: The requests are handled asynchronously, just my requests weren't generated asynchronously.

Comment: The methods in the servlet are synchronous, each individual request is handled synchronously.  However, the container uses separate threads for the individual requests, so they should be executed simultaneously in different threads.  Why do you think the two calls execute serially?

Comment: `Now, when I make two simultaneous requests, the second waits for the first to end. ` for the given code its not true, both will serve in different threads

Comment: what exactly are you seeing in your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By implementation every servlet request runs in a different thread. So it is an asynchronous behaivour.

Comment: Doesn't explain the behaviour he is experiencing though.

Comment: @aioobe - Yes, but maybe he is confused and they run separately in reality. I can't think of any reason.

Comment: After reading this I realized that the browser hadn't generated the requests in an asynchronous way.

Comment: @comco - What does make you think that is synchronous? Maybe the second request was sent slower and the first one had already finsihed.